# Prove an inequality or find a counterexample

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, differential-inequalities

Suppose $\mathcal{M}_1$ represents the space of smooth probability density functions with unit mean, whose support is contained in $[0,\infty)$ (or $\mathbb{R}_+$). Define the following functional $$\mathrm{J}(f):= \int_0^\infty x\frac{(f')^2}{f} \mathrm{d}x$$ for $f \in \mathcal{M}_1.$ I am conjecturing that $$\mathrm{J}(\rho) \leq \mathrm{J}(f) \quad \text{with} \quad \rho(x): = \int_{z\geq x} \frac{(f*f)(z)}{z} \mathrm{d}z,$$ in which $f*f$ denotes the self-convolution of $f$. I have tried some specific examples (even though not too many) and I did not find any counter-examples (analytically or numerically), so I am wondering whether there exists a proof of this conjecture/inequality, if not, a counter-example is welcome!

Comment: certainly not. Take f to be the uniform distribution.

Comment: Thanks.... this seems to be a very good example...

Comment: I have added [a top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are) following a suggestion from chat. I will add that possible improvements to the title were [mentioned in the same message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243?m=58087017#58087017).